# Keep value of input which is generated by Javascript after submitting

Tags: php, jquery

I have this code to append the input panel `#yearPanel` after the select box `#before` changed.

```
$("#before").change(function() {
    var selected = $('#before option:selected').text();

    if(selected == bankShowYear) {
        $(yearPanel).insertAfter("#yearAnchor");
        var value = $("#yearHiden").val();
        $("#year").val(value);
    } else {
        $("#yearPanel").remove();
    }
});
```

I want to keep the input value of `#year` in `#yearPanel` after submitting by PHP. I tried to store the value in `#yearHidden` and assign it to `#year` after all the input are rendered but it doesn't work.

How to keep the input value?

Comment: You might want to add the HTML and PHP to help clarify your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#before").change(function() {
    var selected = $('#before option:selected').text();

    if(selected == bankShowYear) {
        $(yearPanel).insertAfter("#yearAnchor");
        var value = $("#yearHiden").val();
        $("#year").val(value).attr('name', 'year');
    } else {
        $("#yearPanel").remove();
    }
});
```

Then, on your next page:

```
$("#year").value(<?php echo $_REQUEST['year']?>);
```

OR

```
 <input id="year" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['year']?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

your input needs a name attribute in order for it to be passed along to your serverside php script

Comment: still don't see a name attribute in the code.  please add your html so we can clarify

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the value to PHP via a hidden field and PHP will have to render it on the next page. In other words the value needs to go from the client-side to the server-side and back to the client-side.